# Is there a way with HTML to call to another file? Similar to php include?

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

is there an HTML non-php way of calling to a file? For example, I am working on a large site that I don't want to have to edit each page when I want to edit the menu, footer, etc. Sort of like how wordpress uses php to include the header/menu data, I'd like to have one file to edit, but without using php. I don't know how possible this is. I am developing the site with HTML5/Bootstrap/JS and would like to avoid php if possible!

Comment: This has been answered here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file

Answer (score 1):

One method you can use is the `.shtml` file extension.

It also has SSI capabilities and is server-side, not client-side, therefore it runs off the server.

*Server Side Includes (SSI)*

Basic syntax to include files is:

`<!--#include virtual="/footer.html" -->`
`<!--#include file="footer.html" -->`
`<!--#include virtual="/cgi-bin/counter.pl" -->`

You can also include other files inside included files.

For example, say you have a header file `<!--#include virtual="/header.shtml" -->` and you want to include a navigation bar, you just do

`header.shtml` would contain
`<!--#include virtual="/nav.shtml" -->`

all inside the same file, say you call it `index.shtml`

`index.shtml` would contain this structure

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <!--#include virtual="/js_files.shtml" -->
    <!--#include virtual="/metatags.shtml" -->
    <title>
    <!--#include virtual="/title.shtml" -->
    </title>
</head>

<body>
    <!--#include virtual="/header.shtml" -->
    <div>Hello world!</div>
    <!--#include virtual="/footer.shtml" -->

</body>
</html>
```

and inside `<!--#include virtual="/header.shtml" -->`

you could have this tag included in there `<!--#include virtual="/nav.shtml" -->`

containing

```
<a href="index.shtml">Home</a> - 
<a href="about.shtml">About</a> - 
<a href="contact.shtml">Info</a>
```

- By using the same or similar structure for all your files, any change you make to one (include) file, will be affected globally throughout the site.
- This is a method I use myself for certain websites where PHP isn't a requirement and have used for many years and works quite well, including Bootstrap-based.

---

References:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/ssi.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes
- http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/webmaster/article.php/3473341

Answer (score 0):

If your are already using java script lets just use JQuery

Using jQuery:

index.html:

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
    <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#header").load("header.html"); 
      $("#footer").load("footer.html");
    });
    </script> 
  </head> 

  <body> 
     <div id="header"></div>
     <div id="footer"></div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

header.html

```
<p><b> This is my header file </b></p>
```

footer.html

```
<p><b> This is my footer file!</b></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an iframe to include one HTML page inside another page.